# Score increases in Python even with a wrong answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm currently developing a score keeper for a quiz game I'm making.

```
score = 0

bolivia = str(input("Name a capital of Bolivia."))

if (bolivia == "La Paz" or "Sucre"):

    print ("Correct")

    score = score + 50

    print (score)

else:

    print ("You/re incorrect")

input ("Press enter to exit;)")
```

The problem is that if I get the answer wrong it prints this:

```
Correct
50
Press enter to exit;)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any feed back is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
if (bolivia == "La Paz" or "Sucre"):
```

Has the following two statements:

1) `bolivia == "La Paz"`

2) `"Sucre"`

The latter statement `"Sucre"` is a string which is a [Truthy value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-in-python-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false), thus the `if` statement as a whole will pass as they are joined together with the `or` keyword.

What you likely want to evaluate is

```
if bolivia == "La Paz" or bolivia == "Sucre":
```

Or consider the `in` keyword:

```
if bolivia in ("La Paz", "Sucre"):
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your source code is the way you construct the if statement.

You should edit it to look like this:

```
if bolivia == "La Paz" or bolivia == "Sucre":
```

Notice that you should use the bolivia variable again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line `if (bolivia == "La Paz" or "Sucre"):` `or "Sucre"` will always evaluate to true.

You need to check `if (bolivia == "La Paz" or bolivia == "Sucre"):`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the issue you have with your statement is that when you perform boolean logic (`and`/`or` statements here) is that it is evaluated as an expression.

Take the third line in which you have:
`if (bolivia == "La Paz" or "Sucre"):`

Here you have the boolean logic operator `or`. This means it will evaluate each side (or rather is will evaluate the first side.. if that is correct it ignores the second statement.. but that is just a tidbit of extra information).

`bolvia == "La Paz"`
is a valid expression. You are asking if bolvia is equal to the string "La Paz".

`"Sucre"` is not a valid statement. It has no meaning, you must form this into an expression also.

`bolvia == "La Paz" or bolvia == "Sucre"` would be two correct expressions that could be evaluated by an `or` statement.

Now you should have the intended behaviour of your `if` statement.

I would recommend making this more foolproof also by making it case-insensitive. By this I mean you could change the string into the proper format before testing. This would allow for `"sucre"`, `"la paz"` and other possibilities.

This would change your initial statement to

```
bolivia = str(input("Name a capital of Bolivia.")).title()
```

Now in your test statements you could enter `la paz` and then receive `La Paz` as an output.

`score = score + 50` can also be shortened to `score += 50` as this is a shorthand for the former.

This would change your code to the following:

```
    score = 0
    bolivia = str(input("Name a capital of Bolivia.")).title()

    if (bolivia == "La Paz" or bolivia == "Sucre"):
        print ("Correct")
        score += 50
        print (score)
    else:
        print ("You/re incorrect")
        input ("Press enter to exit;)")
```

Hope this helps.